# Best way to make container div over its contents?

Tags: css, jquery-cycle2

If I have a basic cycle2 like on their [demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php):

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

Is there any way to make the outer cycle-slideshow *above* the images with css, so that clicking on the visible image would be actually clicking the container, and background color like rgba(100,100,100,0.5) would be an overlay over every image as they change?

Comment: set z-index: -1 to the images

Comment: make container div over its contents?... do you mean... how they are stacked up? or probably how they are overlayed?